# Internet Slow at Smart Phones

Tags: load-balancing, router, internet

Our office LAN has several smartphones that are experiencing very slow internet speeds but laptops are fine.
We have two internet connection 7+7 mbs put in TP-Link R480T+ Load Balance Broadcast router.
One LAN cable from said router to Server1 installed Windows 2012 R.
DHCP enabled at Server 1. Some gadgets in reservation list.
All staff's gadgets get connection from Server1.
laptops and PCs ' internet fine but smartphones internet very slow. 
[Our Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8xZs.png)

Comment: So, the laptops and PC's also connect via WiFi?

Comment: yes laptops and PCs are also connected with wifi

Comment: A cellular company also applied their devices in our premises for improving their GSM or 3G signals. Is it possible to any conflict with them?

Comment: Those conflicts would be noticeable on the laptops and PC's too.  So we must find another reason, something specific to the smartphones.  Are they both Android and iOS?  Access Points shared between PC's and phones?

Comment: Maximum Android phones 3 to 5 iOS, Access Points shared between PCs and phones.

Comment: Maximum Android phones & 3 to 5 iOS, Access Points shared between PCs and phones. router's DHCP disabled but Server1 is a DHCP provider @GerardH.Pille

Comment: Can you prove the problem is the Wifi?  Eg. download a sizeable file from one of your own servers, via http, not https, to a laptop and to a a smartphone and measure the time it takes.